# Distance matrix, VBA to find out several values for a city given a range

Tags: vba, excel, matrix, distance

I think it's rather difficult this kind of macro to realize especially for me that I'm not very practice in VBA.
So here what I need.
I have a distance matrix in sheet A and my DB in sheet B. In the DB I have a column where I write a city in each cell; a column where a write a km range. When I write a city and the range km (i.e. <=200 or <100) I need that in the next column (so still in sheet B) appears a drop down menu with the names of the nearest cities (according to the distance matrix in sheet A).

I cannot attach a file or a picture, so if someone needs more info please just ask!

I thank anyone who will help me and if you post some macro code, please be kind to explain it so that I can understand it.

Code from the comment below:

```
Sub CercaOrizVert()

Dim CR, CV As Object
R = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set zonaoriz = ActiveSheet.Range([C3], [C3].End(xlToRight))
For Each CR In zonaoriz
  If CR = [A1] Then
    C = CR.Column
    Set zonavert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, C), Cells(R, C))
    For Each CV In zonavert
      If CV = [B1] Then
       CV.Select
       Exit For
       Exit For
      End If
    Next
  End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello! SO is a place where programmers help other programmers. If you have a specific question about programming, go ahead and ask, we will be happy to help. If you just want someone to do your job, you should try a place like freelancer.com.

Comment: As said I'm not good at VBA, I have only created this

'Sub CercaOrizVert()
Dim CR, CV As Object
R = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set zonaoriz = ActiveSheet.Range([C3], [C3].End(xlToRight))
For Each CR In zonaoriz
If CR = [A1] Then
C = CR.Column
Set zonavert = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, C), Cells(R, C))
For Each CV In zonavert
If CV = [B1] Then
CV.Select
Exit For: Exit For
End If
Next
End If
Next
End Sub'

Comment: that mini-macro only allows me to find out 1 single value according to what I write in cell B1. I'm looking for hints...first of all, how can I set a rule so that I find out more than a result??

Comment: Nice puzzling question !

Comment: How is your distance matrix laid out (what data is in column A, B, C, etc)?

How is sheet B arranged? You mention one column for the city, another for the distance, and a third where you want a dropdown for other cities that are within that range. In your code, you reference cell A1 along with the range of C3 and cells containing data to the right of C3. How is all of that structured?

Comment: The distance matrix is 170x170 were 1 row and column are the names of the cities and distances are expressed in Km; the diagonal is made of 0 since it's a city distance from itself.
The B sheet is from a DB, there are severals column included the city column.
In the code I was able to create I made an attempt in the same sheet since I didn't know how to reference to the city in the B sheet